# Deleting row using ArcPy cursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor

I am new to python ArcPy.
   I am trying to delete identical points in feature class.
the code is below:

```
>>> import arcpy
>>> fp=r"D:\NOCAS\TEMP\Belgum transistion.gdb\transistion\CenterlinePoints"
>>> sc=arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fp,["oid@","shape@"])
>>> dictionary={}
>>> for data in sc:
...     dictionary[data[0]]=data[1]
...     
>>> uc=arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fp,["oid@","shape@"])
>>> for row in uc:
...     for r in dictionary:

...         if row[0]!=r:

...             if sd[r].equals(row[1]):

...                 uc.deleteRow()
```

when trying to run the code it delete one point out five identical points and arcmap shutdowned.

Comment: It sounds like a self locking situation, use a with statement, as it stands your search cursor isn't gone and is still locking when you get to the update cursor. **with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fp,["oid@","shape@"]) as sc:** then **for data in sc:**, for the update cursor use **with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fp,["oid@","shape@"]) as uc:** then **for row in uc:** this will ensure the locks are being released.

Comment: Why don't you just use the *delete identical* tool, no need for any code?

Comment: i am new to arcpy i just trying to use updatecursor

Comment: i write code with with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fp,["oid@","shape@"]) as sc: then for data in sc:, for the update cursor use with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fp,["oid@","shape@"]) as uc: then for row in uc: but still not running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the potential to try to delete the same row twice since you have a `for` occuring in each row. `break` out of your `for` loop if a `deleteRow` occurs.

```
>>> for row in uc:
...     for r in dictionary:
...         if row[0]!=r:
...             if sd[r].equals(row[1]):
...                 uc.deleteRow()
...                 break
```